# Security issue with wifi password

Tags: wireless-networking

My ISP, CableOne, has a feature on their site that allows you to retrieve (display on your screen) your wifi password if you are using one of their modems (which I am).  I feel like this is a security issue.  I would like a more informed opinion before I email CableOne's CEO.

Comment: What steps do you have to take to retrieve the password before it is displayed on your screen? Upon retrieval, does it display the current password you actually have, or just the default password that was first assigned to the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i would also hate to be on a site (other than the router itself's web portal) and see my wifi password pop up for any reason (and i **always** lean on the side of paranoid when it comes to Info-Sec), this just isn't enough information to say with any level of certainty that its a security issue.

I think this question belongs on Info-Sec exchange as well instead of super user. Some questions we need to know:

- Exactly where were you and what site or object were you interacting with when the password popped up?
- if you are connected to the hard line and do the same steps does it still work?
- if you are connected to someone else's internet like a mcdonalds cafe, does it still happen?
- What is the model of the router you are using.

Some basic steps would allow us to test things and give a clear answer. But like this, there is no way to say for sure this is a security risk.

Comment: It's true, as Tom Cee pointed out, you have to be signed on to your CableOne account to retrieve you wifi password.  However, I feel like my wifi password should be more protected than my CableOne password.  For instance, I don't store certain passwords, like my bank account password, electronically, because it my computer is hacked, I don't want the hackers to have access to my bank account.  If a hacker were to discover my CableOne password, they would have access to my whole network.  My modem model is ARRIS-8C22.

Comment: The security community and corporate world have long been in tension discussing this. Alot of companies (even banks!) use short, weak password policies to protect entire droves of information. The problem is those systems are easier to manage and cheaper to operate unless a breach happens. Then its cheaper to fix it. But alas, it seems a breach has to happen before major flaws are fixed. You are not alone is worrying about this, and companies are becoming more aware of digital threats... but progress is slow.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about CableOne. I use AT&T, and what they actually do is point you  to the default password printed on the side of the modem/router.

From what I can tell of CableOne's site, you can only get that information if logged into your account. I would suggest that you contact theior customer service with your concern, and if they cannot satify you, either ask for a supervisor or send your email.

good luck